# NodeJS TypeError: sessionsMap[userId].push is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: node.js, nodes

In my nodejs, which need to accept user Notifications via sockets and redis i use:

```
const sessionsMap = {};
RedisClient.subscribe('notification');

RedisClient.on('message', async (channel, message) => {
    if(channel === 'notification') {
        const notification = JSON.parse(message);
        const receiverId = sessionsMap[notification.notification.user_id];

        // console.log(notification);

        io.sockets.to(receiverId).emit('newNotification', notification);

    }
}

    socket.emit('askForUserId');
    socket.on('receivedUserID', async (userId) => {
        const userObject = sessionsMap[userId];
        sessionsMap[userId] = [];

        sessionsMap[userId].push(...userObject);
        sessionsMap[userId].push(socket.id);
    });
```

And always i received error:

```
0|app  | TypeError: sessionsMap[userId].push is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
0|app  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/server/app.js:203:29)
```

At 203 line i have:

`sessionsMap[userId].push(...userObject);`

But i received true user id.

Where can be my problem? How i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `userObject` is an array then you don't want to use the spread operator and push method.

Consider doing this instead

```js
socket.on('receivedUserID', async (userId) => {
  const userObject = sessionsMap[userId];
  sessionsMap[userId] = []
  if (Array.isArray(userObject)) {
    sessionsMap[userId] = [...userObject];
  }

  sessionsMap[userId].push(socket.id);
});
```

Please note that the above will only work if `useObject` is an array, if it's not, then `push` as you're currently doing but without spreading.

```js
sessionsMap[userId].push(userObject);
```

Comment: yes, ny userObject is in array, how i udestand: `const receiverIds = sessionsMap[object.user_id]`, but it doesn't help...

Comment: When you `console.log(sessionsMap[userId])` what does it look like? @yrbet

Comment: now i nothing received, because has error: `(node:23284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: userObject is not iterable
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/dota2.run/dev.dota2.run/server/app.js:199:35)` and in 199 line it's: `sessionsMap[userId] = [...userObject];`

Comment: I strongly believe `userObject` is not an array, or the value is always changing. Try my update

Comment: I just made an edit! Can you try that? @yrbet

Comment: `or the value is always changing` user id has fixed number, but message, which receivd user can be different. one moment, will check

Comment: now i don't received errors, and see my notifications :) what was the problem in the end? because of the array?

Comment: Yeah, it's not always an array, and we can't do `[...userObject]` if it's not an array. Do you mind accepting and upvoting the answer since it helped you? @yrbet